# sbt-assembly: How do I exclude the configuration files in src/main/resources

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using sbtassembly from https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly to package my project.

I'm wondering is there anyway to exclude the resource files?

Answer (score 5):

You can specify files (and paths) to exclude by customizing the `mergeStrategy`:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-specific-files

So for discarding specific file you can do something like this:

```
// build.sbt

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("about.html") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Here's the documentaion for all available strategies:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy

Answer (score 0):

Using Dani's approach with `sbt` 0.13.13, the config files were still included in my jar. This worked, though:

```
excludeFilter in Compile := "myconfig.conf",
```

In my case, all the files have the same name, `myconfig.conf`, but exist within a tree structure under src/main/resources/config. I tried:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += { baseDirectory.value / "src/main/resources/config" },
```

But it removed the directories from the jar, leaving the files.

It's documented here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html