# sbt package: exclude Python files in JAR file

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to figure out how to excluded the Python files from the JAR file generated by the `sbt package` command.

The [Delta lake project](https://github.com/delta-io/delta) uses SBT version 0.13.18 and the JAR file is built with `sbt package`.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
python/
  delta/
    testing/
      utils.py
  tests/
    test_sql.py
src/
  main/
    ...scala files
build.sbt
run-tests.py
```

It follows the standard SBT project structure with a couple of Python files added in.

The Python files are included in the JAR file when `sbt package` is run and I'd like to figure out how to exclude all the Python files.

Here's what I tried adding to the `build.sbt` file:

1. `mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filter(!_._1.getName.endsWith("py")) }` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491505/how-to-exclude-resources-during-packaging-with-sbt-but-not-during-testing)
2. `excludeFilter in Compile := "*.py"` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162016/sbt-assembly-how-do-i-exclude-the-configuration-files-in-src-main-resources)

Neither of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it, but I think something like this when you make a fat jar.

```scala
assemblyMergeStrategry in assembly := {
  case PathList(parts @ _*) if parts.last.endsWith(".py") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first // or whatever you currently have for your other merges
}
```